# Measuring direction of a three phase motor (400VAC, 50 Hz) within a 5V-circuit

Tags: pic, high-voltage, three-phase, voltage-detector

I've got a lot of motor controller boards, without the actual motor, and I'm interested in measuring at the output terminals (U,V, W) to see if there's any voltage. This to just check rudimentally if the boards work.

Since it's three phase output, I also need to check the phase order: U-V-W = forward, W-V-U = backward.

The actual direction is simple to test with a small PIC, but how can I reduce the dangerous voltages to a 5V compatible level? I don't think relays will work due to the fast switching (and tremendous amount of noise), so is there any other safe way?

Comment: Use a decent multimeter with cables in good condition...

Comment: Good tip, but that will take ages for ~30 boards.

Comment: Industrial phase sequence checking device / relay. Small and cheap, also. http://www2.schneider-electric.com/resources/sites/SCHNEIDER_ELECTRIC/content/live/FAQS/174000/FA174284/en_US/RM4TG20.pdf

Comment: You can buy even cheaper phase sequence tester on Ebay, plenty of them.

Comment: Why don't you get a phase sequence meter? The time spent developing and coding your own phase sequence detection will be way higher than buying and using a phase sequence meter.